# Does CUDA matter for Blender performance?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, performance

Does CUDA matter for Blender performance?

What about CUDA and Cycles performance?

What about CUDA and Eevee performance?

Answer (score 3):

Cuda and Optix are both Nvidia exclusive technologies and for the purpose of doing rendering in blender are generally faster than AMD cards using OpenCL technology (though this is largely to do moreso with the monopoly Nvidia has and them not playing nice with AMD rather than their cards inherently being better.) But yes, they are important. If you have a dedicated Nvidia GPU, you will care a lot about Cuda.

Comment: Thank you, katonakob. I want to build desktop computer for Blender. I took your words into consideration. So, I want to use dedicated Nvidia GPU. Does CUDA Important for both Cycles rendering and Eevee rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Blender can use CUDA for rendering with Cycles. It's a very important feature used by a huge part of users of Blender. This technology has a great impact on rendering so it does matter to a lot of people.

Comment: Thank you, Martynas. I took your words into attention. You wrote: "Blender can use CUDA for rendering with Cycles". Thank you. What about CUDA and Eevee?